# Hugo: Use single.html for index pages

Tags: templates, include, hugo, templating

In my Hugo theme, I use the default `layouts/_default/single.html` file to render my content pages and the default `layouts/index.html` file to render all index pages. I don't want to render my index pages differently and would like to have them rendered by `single.html`.

Of course, I don't want to duplicate the code of `single.html` in `index.html`. So, is there a way to to tell Hugo to use `single.html` also for index pages?

I could move the code from `single.html` into a partial and include that in both files, but I am not sure if that is the way to do it in Hugo or if there is already another best practice.

Comment: I think partials are the best way to go. Maybe the only way. You can easily control templates via type, kind, section. But I don't know that Hugo will allow you to redirect a single layout to the "index.html" file, or vice versa. This is actually what many design systems do, using nested templates to construct more sophisticated page layouts. You can look into "component based design" for some of these principles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up adding the following two lines to the front matter of `content/_index.md`:

```
type: _default
layout: single
```

This way, I don't have to put the content of `single.html` into a partial to include it in two places and I don't need `layouts/index.html` anymore. Furthermore, I can use this technique for deeper nested `_index.md` files, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some logical jumps as I think you might not understand hugo templating yet... based on your "index files" comment. So: TLDR; delete index.html in _default and single.html and default and instead have 1 list.html. Should work. Otherwise:

So a few questions compadre.

What do you mean by "index pages" as Only the homepage renders with index.html

https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/
Hugo's lookup order if what you need to read/look at/learn generally.

So, making some jumps logicamente, IF you mean your page branch/leaf bundles (index.md and _index.md)?

Then again, look up your look-up order and you might see /default/list.html as your solutione, but sans /default/index.html - as then list will override - no?

It all depends on what you are trying to do, but first it might be an idea too look up Hugo's basic system/organization in:

https://gohugo.io/templates/introduction/

But the above solution should work - none-the-less.